# Lilygo TTGO T-Beam Guru Meditation Error

Tags: debugging

I have recently purchased a lilygo ttgo t-beam (868Mhz version) on which I try to run the "DeviceInfo" example code provided by TheThingsNetwork. When executing `ttn.ShowStatus();` I see in the Serial Monitor an error stating that "core 1 panic'ed" and the device keeps rebooting eternally.

I am new to this but I think I have not missed any steps. I have included the "TheThingsNetwork" library successfully (the sketch compiles when I include it) and I have added some **Additional Boards Manager URLs** to help Arduino IDE find my board.

So far,

I have added these links to the **Additional Boards Manager URLs**:

http://downloads.sodaq.net/package_sodaq_index.json,

http://downloads.sodaq.net/package_sodaq_samd_index.json,

https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json,

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lauszus/Sanguino/master/package_lauszus_sanguino_index.json,

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json

And I select T-BEAM board.

My sketch is this:

```
#include <TheThingsNetwork.h>

#define loraSerial Serial1
#define debugSerial Serial

// Replace REPLACE_ME with TTN_FP_EU868 or TTN_FP_US915
#define freqPlan TTN_FP_EU868

TheThingsNetwork ttn(loraSerial, debugSerial, freqPlan);

void setup()
{
  loraSerial.begin(57600);
  debugSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  debugSerial.println("Device Information");
  debugSerial.println();
  ttn.showStatus();
  debugSerial.println();
  debugSerial.println("Use the EUI to register the device for OTAA");
  debugSerial.println("-------------------------------------------");
  debugSerial.println();

  delay(10000);
}
```

and this is the error message I get on debugSerial:

[image]

In my understanding this is either a problem with the board I select (TBeam) or a possible but on TheThingsNetwork library.

I would appreciate some help to run this script successfully so I can register my device on TheThingsNetworkor, or at least debug further this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: LoadProhibited usually means that you're trying to read data from an uninitialized pointer. Maybe there's a step you missed, like `ttn.begin()` or something?

Comment: For this device you can't get the EUI that way (I can't tell you why). What can you do is to go to TTN > Register new device > Device EUI (Press the button for generating the automatic key).  
This is just a temporary fix. The correct way to get the EUI is by generating it from the MAC address. You can find some examples online. I did not succed in doing it, but the automatically generated EUI works. Please let me know if you succed in working with ttgo t-beam because I did not :) and I would like to know more!